# Border in aside

Tags: html, css

I have this css code:

```
    aside{
    border: 3px solid black;
        width: 15%;
        padding-left: 25px;
        padding-right: 25px;
        float:right;
        background-color: red;
        overflow-y: auto;
        min-height: 95.3vh;
        flex-warp: warp;
    }

  square{
    border: 3px solid black;
     width: 10%;
     height: 10%;
    background-color: green;

  }
```

And I have this HTML

```
<aside>
        <div class="square">
                Hello
        </div>
</aside>
```

The problem is: I don't have any border for hello as you can see in the next image:
[image]

I wold like to be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your CSS, you're selecting the element `square`, while there's only a class `square`. When selecting a class, include a `.` at the start:

```css
aside{
        border: 3px solid black;
        width: 15%;
        padding-left: 25px;
        padding-right: 25px;
        float:right;
        background-color: red;
        overflow-y: auto;
        min-height: 95.3vh;
        flex-warp: warp;
    }

 .square{
     border: 3px solid black;
     /* width: 10%; 
     height: 10%; */
     background-color: green;

  }
```

```html
<aside>
        <div class="square">
                Hello
        </div>
</aside>
```

Note, this resulted in only the `H` in `Hello` to be colored green with a border. To color the entirety of `Hello`, I removed `width: 10%;` and `height 10%;`

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS properties are being properly applied to the tag  as your CSS selects the tag which is on the html page. However, when selecting a class, in your case, "square", you must select it with the class selector. Instead, in your CSS code, change `square` to `.square`

Eg.

```
.square{
     border: 3px solid black;
     width: 10%; 
     height: 10%;
     background-color: green;
  }
```